# Skype for business chat redirect URI -> SIP: is not redirecting to particular chat

Tags: android, redirect, android-intent, sip, skype-for-business

I tried below code to redirect to skype for business and open particular chat page of particular email id. The same solution is working fine for iOS but for android it's redirecting but chat page is not opening.

```
    mySkypeUri="xyz@gmail.com"
    Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse("sip:" + mySkypeUri);
    Intent skypeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);
    startActivity(skypeIntent);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I can't get this to work either.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to start a chat then that string should look like:

skype:[insert your SkypeName]?chat

```
mySkypeUri="xyz@gmail.com"
Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse("skype:" + mySkypeUri + "?chat");
Intent skypeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);
startActivity(skypeIntent);
```

Comment: Hi ! I am asking for Skype for business which is not Skype .. I need to open chat page in Skype ft business which is previously called as Lync